# How to delete a particular line which has occurred many times in the file in vim

Tags: vim, filtering

I want to delete a line: `This is an example`, which occurs multiple times in a file. How do I go about it.

Thanks,
Alisha

Comment: Do you want to only remove lines that exactly match your string or ones that contain it as a substring as well?

Comment: No i want to delete only the lines having this complete string

Comment: That's not what I meant & it's still not clear what you want.  There's 3 options (1) Do you want to delete the whole line for `This is an example line with extra characters`?  Or (2) only the string `This is an example` (leaving ` line with extra characters`, or (3) don't alter this line at all because it has extra characters.

Comment: The line contains only this string--> "This is an example". So I would want to delete this whole line

Answer (score 16):

You could do:

```
:g/This is an example/d
```

Answer (score 3):

```
:%s/This is an example\n//gc

% indicates all lines of a file
s indicates pattern to be searched.
g for global replacement
c for confirmation on each replace
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete the lines containing **only** the exact match you could:

```
:g/^This is an example$/d
```

Comment: I think you mean :g in the above

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using an external command:

```
:%!grep -v "This is an example"
```

This filters the entire file through the given command. The `grep -v` command selects all the lines of the file that do *not* match the given regular expression.

Comment: Worth noting that this would remove any lines which had "This is an example" as a sub-string, it's not clear from the question if this is desired.

Comment: That's true. If an exact match only is desired, use `"^This is an example$"`.

Comment: If the line is: `autoload_reg_data[i].data = 0x0;` then what would be the change to the above command?